# Jquery Autocomplete - how to send all data to php file while autocomplete

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-autocomplete

I have a problem on this tutorial.
http://www.script-tutorials.com/autocomplete-with-php-jquery-mysql-and-xml

I have 2 inputs:

```
<input id="ra" type="text" autocomplete="off">
<input id="rb" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

I want to send the data of the 2 inputs to a .php file while an input is being typed in or during autocomplete like this:

```
 $('#ra).autocomplete('data.php?mode=ra&rb='+$('#rb').val(), {
        width: 200,
        max: 5
    });

 $('#rb).autocomplete('data.php?mode=rb&ra='+$('#ra').val(), {
        width: 200,
        max: 5
    });
```

But it's not working, how can I make this work?
Thanks.

Comment: You could use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Well...you don't close the ID selector in the example...  What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: i typing wrong,but it's still not working

Comment: Not working how? What is it doing?

Comment: i re-typing like @j_freyre, but it's not working. i tested that script.js run one time. i don't understand lib's mechanism a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are wrong.

Try this

```
 $('#ra').autocomplete('data.php?mode=ra&rb='+$('#rb').val(), {
        width: 200,
        max: 5
    });

 $('#rb').autocomplete('data.php?mode=rb&ra='+$('#ra').val(), {
        width: 200,
        max: 5
    });
```